# How assert that a TIFF file conforms to standard?

Tags: qt, tiff

Today, I use FreeImage 3.15.4.0 to generate TIFF images. Some of my users tells me that he cannot read such images because its library (C++/QT I think) can't read them.

The images generated are readable with ImageJ and some other image processing tools.

So I wonder:

- <del>How to be sure that my image respect the standard (FreeImage rely on libtiff 4.0.3)?</del>
- Are my images too complex? (32 bits float images)
- Does a simple standard format exist for 32 bits depth float images?

*EDIT*

I check by hand that my image followed the format described by adobe: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf.

So, does exist a library comparative to know what part of specification is supported by which library?

Comment: Please show us exact error message. We need to be sure that the problem is not that "qtiff.dll" is not found on user's machne. And also add your version of Qt in the question.

Comment: Gosh another @Ilya ! I wonder how SO will handle this in comments...

Comment: I ask them such details, but I do not have reply yet. But I know that the image has been opened but its content seems incoherent.

Comment: Are you sure that FreeImage uses libtiff ? Qt also uses that lib as a backend, so that should work.

Comment: According to http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/news.html, freeimage use libtiff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to 3 questions: yes.

The fact is QT, like others, is not able to display 32 bits float images: This is not supported by the QImage class (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#Format-enum).

So the user will have to convert the image in something QT (the system in fact) is able to display.